# Google Photos for iOS: sync photo delete actions

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, google-photos

I use Apple Photos (and iCloud) on my iPhone for my photo library. I often take a number of pictures and later delete many of them to only leave the best picture of a set.

I also use Google Photos to make a copy of my iPhone Photo library that is shared with my partner. Google Photos correctly syncs all of my iPhone photos, except when a photo is deleted from Apple Photos: when a photo is deleted from Apple Photos, it remains in Google Photos.

Is there a way to configure Google Photos to sync both photo additions and photo delete actions from my Apple Photos library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your best bet might be to do the deletions from the Google Photos app. That will offer the option to also delete from your Apple Photos library, while also syncing to your partner's phone.

Comment: Oh! I didn’t know it would ask me if I also wanted to delete from Apple Photos! Good tip, thanks :)